# use variable on color change but fails

Tags: pine-script

It's my first script in Pine and I have a problem to use a var on colour change. I have the variable `h4_high_col` from an input

```
h4_high_col = input(title="H4 High Color", defval="fuchsia", options=["red", "orange", "fuchsia"])
```

now I tried to use this variable on colour change

```
level1_h4_col = close >= level1_h4 ? color.aqua : "color."+h4_high_col
```

I tried a lot of different ways but always have errors

```
line 61: Cannot call 'operator ?:' with arguments (series[bool], const color, input string); available overloads:
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know how to convert string to variable name, but this solution might help you

```
h4_high_col = input(title="H4 High Color", defval="fuchsia", options=["red", "orange", "fuchsia"])
level1_h4_col = close >= open ? color.aqua : h4_high_col=="fuchsia"?color.fuchsia:h4_high_col=="orange"?color.orange:h4_high_col=="red"?color.red:na
```